# how to get a Popup by id in OpenLayers map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

When initial the map, I created many popup for features

```
var popup= new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
    id, //id
    new OpenLayers.LonLat(msg.reviseLng, msg.reviseLat),
    new OpenLayers.Size(160,100),
    '<html></html>',
    null,
    true);
    popup.autoSize=false;
    map.addPopup(popup);
```

but I can not get a exist popup when I location a point ,I want get it by it's id and show it, please help me

Answer (score 0):

The idea should be: when the user click on a certain point recognized by you, the popup should be displayed, isn't it?

You can do it in this way:

```
map.events.register("click", map , function(e){
   // Look for point... (your code)

   // Point detected!

   // now we need to take the popup identified by 'popupid' identifier and show it
   for(var i=0; i<map.popups.length; i++){
      if(map.popups[i].id == myid){
         map.popups[i].show();
         break;
      }
   }
});
```